# Djangocms_blog - how to include social media (ie. facebook)

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-cms

I'm using [djangocms_blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog). Everything is working good, but I have no idea how to include facebook for articles. Plugin give me possible for that, but I never do that and I don't know where I find relevant information about it.

How it look on my djangocms admin:
[image]

I created app on facebook dev:

[image]

And I used facebook app ID in my blog input on settings.
Like can you see, there is more information about FB. Where can I find them? And What else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the informations are actualy optional, and you can provide any combination of them.
In case you created the application, App id is the right one, probably you will also want **Facebook author URL** (the user profile) or **Facebook page URL** to link the post to the facebook profiles.
Don't forget to enable generic django meta support (at least **META_USE_OG_PROPERTIES**: https://django-meta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#meta-use-og-properties)

Comment: Ok tnx, but to add share and like button I need to add custom js from facebook developer page?

Comment: You can choose whatever sharing widget most suit your needs, the stock facebook ones or others (like addthis etc), that usually goes into  the templates

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, custom djangocms-blog not possess that?

Comment: Nope. 
On purpose: social media sharing widgets are very specific to the project needs and thus not suitable for a reusable app.
djangocms-blog provides only the most flexible social media metadata

Comment: Ok great ;) Now I know everything about that ;) Tnx

Comment: Sorry I just switch off browser ;)